# How can I specify a method as a parameter of my method?

Tags: c#, methods

New to C#, how can I create a method that will accept a method as one of its parameters?

Sounds little weird but I hope that it will be supported in c#.

That what I tried:

```
public void CalculateRepairedCars(int total, /*here I want to pass a method..*/)
{
    ...
}
```

This is the method which I would like to pass:

```
public int Calculate{int totalCars, Condition condition}
{
...
}
```

Comment: This is pretty straightforward, but the exact type of the parameter would depend on what the signature of the method you want to accept is. Look at the `Func` and `Action` classes.

Comment: why would you want to do this? but you can pass in an Action or Func delegate instead

Comment: @Ahmedilyas There could be any number of reasons for doing this. One obvious example would be invoking a callback upon completion of the method.

Comment: @user3399628 - im very aware. I was just curious to know what your reason was - what the context was and if you are going down the right path

Answer (score 7, accepted):

"Putting a method inside a value" (which you can then do many things with, such as passing as an argument to another method) in C# is called *creating a [delegate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173171.aspx)* to that method.

A delegate has a type that directly corresponds to the signature of the method it points to (i.e. the number and types of its arguments and the return value). C# offers ready-made types for delegates that do not return a value ([`Action`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.action%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and its siblings) and for those that do ([`Func`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534960%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and its siblings).

In your case, the signature of `Calculate` matches the type [`Func<int, Condition, int>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534647%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) so you would write

```
public void CalculateRepairedCars(int total, Func<int, Condition, int> calc)
{
    // when you want to invoke the delegate:
    int result = calc(someCondition, someInteger);
}
```

and use it like

```
CalculateRepairedCars(i, Calculate);
```

Comment: "Putting a method inside a value" what does it mean?

Comment: @user3399628: Think of it as "putting a method inside a variable", e.g. `Func<int, Condition, int> f = Calculate`. Only the variable doesn't really need to exist; see how I am passing `Calculate` to the method without defining a variable first. I hope that helps :)

Comment: `f` is not a variable?

Comment: @user3399628: It is. But you don't necessarily need to declare one to call `CalculateRepairedCars`. *Inside* `CalculateRepairedCars`, `calc` is a variable of delegate type.

Answer (score 3):

There are multiple ways. I've used an [`Action`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.action%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to do it before.

```
private void SomeMethod()
{
    CalculateRepairedCars(100, YetAnotherMethod);
}

public void CalculateRepairedCars(int total, Action action)
{
    action.Invoke();  // execute the method, in this case "YetAnotherMethod"
}

public void YetAnotherMethod()
{
    // do stuff
}
```

If the method being passed as a parameter has parameters itself, (such as `YetAnotherMethod(int param1)`), you'd pass it in using [`Action<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/018hxwa8%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
CalculateRepairedCars(100, () => YetAnotherMethod(0));
```

In my case, I didn't have to return a value from the method passed as a parameter. If you have to return a value, use [`Func`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534960%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and its related overloads.

---

Just saw you updated your code with the method you're calling.

```
public int Calculate(int totalCars, Condition condition)
{
    ...
}
```

To return a value, you'd need `Func`:

```
public void CalculateRepairedCars(int total, Func<int, string, int> func)
{
    var result
        = func.Invoke(total, someCondition);  // where's "condition" coming from?

    // do something with result since you're not returning it from this method
}
```

Then call it similar to before:

```
CalculateRepairedCars(100, Calculate);
```

Answer (score 1):

The c# method type is called **delegate**. You declare it, assign a method and then you can do many things with it including passing it as a parameter. Look it up! Note: delegates are *sort of type safe* in that the must share the **signature** with the methods they point to.